# Check if arraylist doesn't contain a prefix

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

So I'm trying to solve this algorithm but I just can't get it figured out.

I have an algorithm that will take two arraylists, one containing the source words and one containing prefixes. The source list will contain words like car, hello, goodbye. The prefix will contain things like c, hel, goo, hi. It will check if the prefix is in the source list, and add that source item to a merged list. I have this part working great. My issue is I also need to take a prefix that doesn't have a match in source, and add it to the merged list as well.

So far my algorithm will add the prefixes for every word it was compared to in the source list, for example the prefix c, it will return c twice because hello and goodbye don't contain c. The issue is that it shouldn't be returning c at all because c has a match in the source list. I can't seem to wrap my head around this algorithm..

I'll just use pseudo code for now as I just mainly want help in logic, either by explaining in words or coding examples. The following should output this list (cat, dog, vi) as cat and dog both have a prefix, and vi is a prefix without a source, so it should be added to the list.

ALGORITHM:

```
arraylist source (cat, dog, vehicle)
arraylist prefix (c, do, vi)
Method: Pass in two arraylists source and prefix
arraylist mergedlist
for (int x - prefix) //loop through prefix list
  for (int y - source) //loop through source list
    if source startsWith prefix
      add that source item to merged list
```

The code I have representing this works great. I tried to add a method right after that if statement as follows:

```
if source DOES NOT start with prefix
  add that prefix to list
```

Obviously this isn't enough to work, but I don't know what else to do. This will just add the prefix every time a prefix doesn't match with a source word it is being compared against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one more list - `unusedPrefixes` - and then add that list to `mergedList` at the end. This ends up using more memory though.

```
arraylist source (cat, dog, vehicle)
arraylist prefix (c, do, vi)
Method: Pass in two arraylists source and prefix
arraylist mergedlist, unusedPrefixes
for (int x - prefix) //loop through prefix list
  bool used = false;
  for (int y - source) //loop through source list
    if source startsWith prefix
      add that source item to merged list
      used = true;
  if !used
    add prefix to unusedPrefixes
add unusedPrefixes to mergedList
```